# In Notepad++ in a csv file, is there a way to highlight the header name of the column you're working in?

Tags: csv, notepad++, highlight

I could have sworn I saw someone do this in the past.

If I have a .csv column and I click into the data, is there a way to have the header row of the column I am working in be highlighted?

If not, is there any other way I can easily tell what column I'm in?  My current display just has Line, Column (but column meaning just the number of characters, not the actual column by comma), and position.

Thanks in advance.

I checked the View Menu, Tools Menu, and Plugins Menu, but nothing is jumping out at me as obvious.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't do it natively, but it's possible thanks to a plugin like [CSV Lint](https://github.com/BdR76/CSVLint)